# How to check if two DAGs after merge of 2 nodes will not have cycles?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given 2 random DAGs, which may or may not have common nodes. We randomly pick one node from each, and call them A and B respectively. `A != B`.

How to check before merging, that if we merge node B into node A (by copying edges from B to edges in A, and destroying the node B), there will be no cycles?

I want to avoid exhaustive search - when we 'virtually' merge this nodes and then for all nodes in resulting graph search for paths from this node to itself.

A Node has unique ID and roughly defined like this:

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    # set of outgoing nodes
    self.deps = set()
    # set of incoming nodes
    self.dependants = set()

# in the end, I want to write function like this:
def check(A, B):
  assert isinstance(A, Node) and isinstance(B, Node)
  if "there will be no cycles":
    return True # we can merge
  else:
    return False # we can not merge
```

I do not need the code, algorithm description or algorithm name would be enough.

Comment: Stating the (hopefully) obvious for completeness: If the original DAGs have no nodes in common, the result of merging will not have any cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When `B` is not a predecessor of `A` there is no cycle.
- If `B` is a direct predecessor of `A` and `B` without the edge to `A` is not a predecessor of `A`. there is no cycle
- otherwise there is a cycle

Hmm, pseudo code

```
if not A in DFS(B) // B is not a predecessor
  return noCycle
if A in B.outEdges and not A in DFS(B less A-Edge) // direct predecessor
  return noCycle
return cycle
```

which can be optimized to

```
if not A in DFS(B less A-Edge) 
  return noCycle
return cycle
```

Consider

```
B->C->A
```

Merging A and B will result in

```
C->A->C
```

Which is a cycle.

```
B->A
 ->C
```

Becomes

```
A->C
```

Where

```
B->A
 ->C->A
```

becomes a cycle

```
A->C->A
```

Comment: Implemented this in my code and these rules seem to be working good. Thanks a lot!